# How do you find the permissions for a SQL Server table_type?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, user-defined-types

Hopefully a simple question here:

How do I get the permissions for an SQL Server `table_type`?

I know how to grant them, ie like:

```
GRANT [permission] ON TYPE::[schema_name].[type_name] TO [user]
```

As per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174346.aspx.

What I want to know however, is how to find out what permissions users already have on a particular table_type.  I've tried looking through tables like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES`, `sys.database_permissions` and `sys.syspermissions`, but I haven't had any luck.

My guess is I'm either missing something obvious or that the privileges for table_types are stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the user_type_id from sys.table_types to join to sys.database_permissions:

```
SELECT prmssn.*
FROM sys.table_types AS tt INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS prmssn ON prmssn.major_id=tt.user_type_id 
WHERE tt.name='<Table-Type Name>' 
    AND SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)='<SchemaName>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.database_permissions a
  JOIN sys.database_principals b on a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id
   where major_id=object_id('dbo.TableNameHere')
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is not a table but a table_type.  And trying `dbo.MyTypeName` does not return any results, unfortunately.